# How do I keep the div in the center of the page and not have so much space between the text and image?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I want the div with the heading, p text, and image to be aligned in the center of the page and also not have all that space between each tag. I think I was able to center-align it correctly but I'm having trouble removing all that distance between the text and image. I want a bit of space between them, but not as much space where it looks too far away and makes the page too long.

I'm using Dreamweaver and when I preview the webpage in Chrome browser, it shows the heading, p text and image all having a bunch of space between them - like they're too spaced away from each other. (Also, for some reason it doesn't look as spaced out when I run the code snippet here like it does in Dreamweaver?) I hope this makes sense, if not I can elaborate more. Thank you.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: lato, sans-serif;
}
.hero{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
.navbar{
    margin: 30px auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 25px;
}
ul{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
}
ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 25px;
}
ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}
ul li a::after{
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 10px;
    background: #f14a60;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: -35px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
ul li a:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
}
.banner{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
.center-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.center-column p {
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 46px;
    margin-right: 46px;
    margin-bottom: 46px;
    margin-left: 46px;
    position: relative;
    top: -11%;
}
.menu {
    top: -75px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="hero">
    <div class="navbar">
        <img id="logo" src="../Images/logo-1.png" width="180" alt="logo">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="./about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="./menu.html">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="./promo.html">Promotions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="center-column">
                <h1 style="font-size: 50px; padding-top: 30px"><span>Our</span> Menu</h1>
                <p class="center-column p">We start bright and early each morning preparing exceptional ingredients to deliver a breakfast and brunch experience that feels good and tastes even better.</p>
                <img class="menu" src="../images/menu.png" width="800" alt="restaurant menu">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>      
</body>
```

Comment: The spacing is because of the margin and padding css attributes being high.

Comment: You can center the div by applying margins or, bad practice, you could use the HTML center tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the same parent class to Paragraph tag. So it's min-height becomes also 100vh. You can practice this one.

```
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: lato, sans-serif;
  }
  .hero {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .navbar {
    margin: 30px auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 25px;
  }
  ul {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
  }
  ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 25px;
  }
  ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
  }
  ul li a::after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 10px;
    background: #f14a60;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: -35px;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  ul li a:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .banner {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 80px;
  }
  .center-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 140vh;
  }
  .center-column p {
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 46px;
    margin-right: 46px;
    margin-bottom: 46px;
    margin-left: 46px;
    position: relative;
    top: -11%;
  }
  .menu {
    top: -75px;
    position: relative;
  } 




<div class="hero">
    <div class="navbar">
      <img
        id="logo"
        src="https://cdn.logo.com/hotlink-ok/logo-social-sq.png"
        width="180"
        alt="logo"
      />
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="../index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="./about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="./menu.html">Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="./promo.html">Promotions</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
      <div class="center-column">
        <h1 style={{ fontSize: "50px", paddingTop: "30px" }}>
          <span>Our</span> Menu
        </h1>
        <p class=" p">
          We start bright and early each morning preparing exceptional
          ingredients to deliver a breakfast and brunch experience that
          feels good and tastes even better.
        </p>
        <img
          class="menu"
          src="https://cdn.logo.com/hotlink-ok/logo-social-sq.png"
          width="300"
          height="300"
          alt="restaurant menu"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You're brilliant, thank you so much for the help! I didn't even realize how simple the fix was or catch the mistake that was causing this issue. I fixed it and it looks perfect, thanks again! :)